# Can clients report bugs and issues into Jira without being setup as a user?

Tags: pm-software, jira

I'm looking at implementing Jira (and add-ons) for our team to manage projects and bug-tracking. Obviously I will set the team up as Users but do clients need to be setup as Users to report bugs and issues? I can see Jira has a capture feedback functionality, but will this also create a Jira issue automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take a look at [Jira Issue Collector](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin).  An excerpt from its docs:

> Need to capture feedback on your website or web application?  Want to make it easy for end users to directly create bugs so your developers can act on them?
>   If you develop web-applications or web sites, the JIRA Issue Collector is the best way to turn your customers' and users' feedback and problems directly into JIRA issues, **all without requiring a JIRA login**.

Yes, the captured feedback goes straight into JIRA in the project you specify, so your team can act on that feedback.

[image]

However, opening a direct way to gather feedback has its disadvantages, and you have to define rules on how to process the feedback efficiently:

- Often, your users are not technical people. They simply can't provide with **quality bug report** that could be directly processed. It may lack Environment, Steps To Reproduce, Expected, or Actual Result, attached logs or screenshots;
- Even more, since the users aren't registered, it is hard to retrieve missing info;
- Since the users don't search for existing issues, you will likely get many duplicates;
- Obviously, the users are unable to track how their issue progresses;

The best way, I think, is to assign someone to review all incoming issues, then make them "real" bugs assignable to your development team.

Comment: +1 for the perfect answer. Issue Collectors do record some Environment info by default (specifically URL, User-Agent and screen resolution) and you can customise it with JavaScript to pass other info straight to JIRA (see https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Use+of+the+JIRA+Issue+Collector)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use the feedback functionality to capture issues from your customers as it is intended to capture feedback from end users but you might want to take the issue submitted via feedback and capture it as a issue in JIRA so you can track it for internal purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You could always have Jira [capture issues via email](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email).

Comment: awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can allow anonymous access to a project. We use this for some projects for comments, you may be able to extend this to raising a ticket as well.